# Terminal: disable printing/output of keyboard commands

Tags: terminal, bash

I have the same problem as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756825/ctrl-d-on-mac-terminal-outputs-a-d-character) – I am running a C script and somehow when I pass the EOF signal with Ctrl+D, `^D` gets printed to the console.

My question is therefore: is it possible to disable outputting `^D` and `^C` and the like whenever you press Ctrl+D/Ctrl+C?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!